# Python: How to reference element of a tuple that is in a dictionary

Tags: python

for example I have a dict var defined as below:

```
var{m:(a, b)}
```

And now I want to reference the value of 'a' in a for loop

suppose var is filled with some instances as below

```
var = {0: {'1a': (502, 2)}, 1: {'2b': (103, 3)}}
```

Comment: Do you know how to reference items in a tuple or list? Like `t = ('a', 'b', 'c')` implies `t[0] == 'a'`? If so and this doesn't solve the question, please elaborate on how you want to reference `a` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so you want `v[0]['1a'][0]`

EDIT: In response to your comment, you probably want:

```
for key, value in v[k].items():
  print value[0]
```

Comment: v[0]['1a'][0] is based on the knowledge of what's in v, but what if you don't know and you want to refer that 'a' in for loop as: for k, v in var.iteritem:    v[k][?][0]. How do fill the '?'? Sorry about the format of this comment, don't know how to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are wanting:

```
var = {0: {'1a': (502, 2)}, 1: {'2b': (103, 3)}}

for m, elements in var.items():
    for a, b in elements.values():
        print a
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want, rather:

```
for k, (v1, v2) in var.iteritems():
    print v1
```

Or if not all of your dict values are going to have two items (or if your version of Python doesn't do multilevel tuple unpacking):

```
for k, v in var.iteritems():
    print v[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this generic example can make it clear by naming the items we get descriptively.

```
var = {0: {'1a': (502, 2)}, 1: {'2b': (103, 3)}}
```

You want to iterate on all dicts that var contains and iterate on what they contain.

```
for number, innerdict in var.items(): # first time around number is e.g. 0 and innerdict is e.g. {'1a': (502, 2)}
    print number
    for numberletter, tup in innerdict.items(): # first time around numberletter is e.g. 1a and tup is e.g. (502, 2) 
        print numberletter, tup
        for tuplenumber in tup: # first time around tuplenumber is e.g. 502
            print tuplenumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var = {'m':('a', 'b'), 'n': ('c','d')}

a_coords = [(k,v.index('a')) for k,v in var.iteritems() if 'a' in v ]
```

Result:

```
>>> a_coords
[('m', 0)]
```

`'m'` is the key that is associated with the value of a tuple that holds a, and `0` is the index where a is located.